# Import Error when trying to make python 2 modul

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module, python-packaging

This doesn't seem to be an issue in python 3 but I'm needing to use python 2.7 for this and get the following issue

```
DIRECTORY STRUCTURE
module
├── __init__.py
└── submodule
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

```py
# module/__init__.py
from module import submodule

# module/submodule/__init__.py
from module.submodule import test

# module/submodule/test.py
from module import submodule
```

when I try to import module from somewhere else it results in the following error:

```
>>> import module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "module/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module import submodule
  File "module/submodule/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module.submodule import test
  File "module/submodule/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module import submodule
ImportError: cannot import name submodule
```

I'm assuming the issue has something to do with circular imports but i need to use submodule in both module/__init__.py and module/submodule/test.py

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned circular imports, one way to resolve this is by importing the module locally.

For e.g.

```
def fun():
    from module import submodule
```